# "Create test" for a method creates and empty stub without even invoking the method under test?

Tags: pycharm

In a python class/script I created a fictional method `read()`:

```py
    def read(
        self,
        resource: str,
        spark_schema: str = None,
        custom_options: Optional[dict] = None,
    ) -> DataFrame:
        return None
```

Then I created a "new" test for it and the result is this:

```py
def test_read():
    assert False
```

There was no offer to invoke the method-under-test with its actual parameters and in fact there is no invocation of the method at all!  What is the point of generating  a testcase for a method that never calls it?

Is this the expected behavior or is there some settings that need to be tweaked?  I have noted this behavior across all projects that I work on.

I am on `Pycharm Pro 2022.2.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the expected behavior

Yes.

> What is the point of generating a testcase for a method that never calls it?

There is no way that the stub generator can know either what functionality you want the new test to check, nor what the correct result should be. It might be able to deduce that a test for `read` should involve `read` at some point, and it might be able to deduce that calling `read` entails providing a `resource`, `spark_schema` and `custom_options`. It might even be able to check the type annotations.

However, there is no way it could know (AI would at most allow it to pretend) what sensible values are for those parameters, let alone useful ones for a test. There is certainly no way it could know anything about what the return value should be, or about anything else that should happen. It also has no way to know what setup or teardown is appropriate for calling the function, or if there is any good reason for a test to involve calling the function more than once, etc. etc. etc.

If it guessed at any of these things (especially if it leaned on AI), it would risk introducing a test that people accept without thinking, which might pass or fail but in a way that is **completely meaningless**.

---

Note carefully that the stub chooses to say `assert False`, rather than `assert True`. This is deliberate: since the test will always fail unless actual logic is filled in, if filling in a "real" test is neglected then there will be clear evidence of that.

On the other hand, the stub documents an intent to write a test for the method. If the stub hadn't been generated at all, it would be that much easier to forget writing the test entirely.

Further, a failing test is evidence *that the test harness works and is capable of reporting errors*.

This is [conventional TDD wisdom that has been explained countless times over](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=always+write+a+failing+test+first).

Comment: Well I disagree with this behavior: the testing harness could put in default parameters at the very least as an option.  But i'll award in the sense of "don't shoot the messenger" that provides the useful  information even if not the answer we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

While not a direct answer I found a github repo utility that does more or less what I was looking/hoping for:  [pytestgen](https://github.com/Figglewatts/pytestgen)

```
pip3 install pytestgen
```

```py
def test_kustoreader_read(instance, resource, spark_schema, custom_options, expected):
    # TODO: write test for test_kustoreader_read
    # result = instance.read(resource, spark_schema, custom_options)
    # assert result == expected
    pass
```